# Loading csv data from a pre HTML block in Highcharts/Highstock

Tags: csv, highcharts

My data is a CSV-formatted PRE block in the following format:

```
<pre id="data.csv" style="display: none">
date,stock_ticker_symbol,amount
2016-07-29,aapl,104.19
2016-07-29,msft,56.68
2016-07-29,adbe,97.86
2016-07-28,aapl,104.34
2016-07-28,msft,56.21
2016-07-28,adbe,98.44
2016-07-27,aapl,102.95
2016-07-27,msft,56.19
2016-07-27,adbe,97.93
</pre>
```

I try to load this in Highstock using the following code:

```
data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('data.csv').innerHTML
}
```

But it is not working. I get error #14. I think HighStock thinks the stock ticker symbols are supposed to be numerical values, but those aren't until the next column. How do I change the data { csv: } code to interpret the pre block correctly?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/cu60h47w/

Comment: Your data is not in good format for Highcharts, here you can find information how your csv should look like. If you need to use this data, you can preprocess it after loading this data to your chart, see this API parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.parsed